# when I run rake assets:precompile got couldn't find file 'jquery' in application.js on //= require jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

when I run

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I got

```
couldn't find file 'jquery'
```

in application.js on line:

```
//= require jquery
```

Rails 3.2.2. What is reason?

Answer (score 4):

I'd venture to say you don't have a jquery.js file anywhere in your app. If it's not in app/assets or vendor/assets or lib/assets, add it to one of them -- or if you are using the jquery-rails gem, follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails).

Comment: it shouldn't be in lib/assets or vendor/assets, because in Gemfile: 
gem 'jquery-rails'

Comment: well, you didn't actually mention that you were using the gem, but since you have now did you do a "bundle install" and, if so did it complete successfully?

Comment: yes, sorry. Bundle install completed successfully.  If I uncomment Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))) from development.rb - it processed locally, but not on production.

Comment: check your rvm/rbenv see your gems

Answer (score 4):

If you're running in production you must comment out the line

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
```

and uncomment the following

```
Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
```

since by default gems included in the "assets" group specified in the Gemfile won't be added in the production environment.

This lead me to a similar situation in which I was running a precompile in production but Uglifier kept throwing me a "couldn't find jquery error" but clean compile in development.

Comment: This is partially the correct answer. I moved jquery-rails out of the assets group and things work again.

Comment: `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` is equivalent to `bundle exec rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets`, meaning it will automatically include the assets group from the Gemfile. No need to change the Bundler.require line.